# Find biggest Circle having all points close to a List of Polygons

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry

### Setting

Imagine a List of polygons `polys` (type: `BoundaryMeshRegion`, polygons may also overlap):

```
pnts = {{0.3, 0}, {4, 2}, {4, -2}};
rotpnts = Table[RotationTransform[2*Pi/3*i][pnts], {i, 0, 2}];
polys = BoundaryMeshRegion[#, Line[{1, 2, 3, 1}]] & /@ rotpnts;
Show[polys]
```

[image: my_polygons]

### Question

What is the radius of the biggest circle (center in `{0,0}`), whose inner points do not exceed a given (i.e. freely definable) distance `dmax`to at least one of the polygons of `polys`?

**Ideas**

- The circle may continuously grow and then checked, if still every point on it is closer than `dmax` to one of the polygons
- "some" Voronoi approach

[image: sketch of question]

### Extra Question (solved)

Return the indices of the `polys`-list of the `n` closest polygons to a given point `p`.

**Illustration**

[image: closest_n_polys]

For `n=2` I would get a list of indices `{3,1}`, as `polys[[3]]` is the nearest polygon to `p` and `polys[[1]]` the second closest.

**Illustrating Manipulate - Solution**

```
pnts = {{0.3, 0}, {4, 2}, {4, -2}};
rotpnts = Table[RotationTransform[2*Pi/3*i][pnts], {i, 0, 2}];
polys = BoundaryMeshRegion[#, Line[{1, 2, 3, 1}]] & /@ rotpnts;

Manipulate[
 testPt = p;
 allPts = RegionNearest[#, p] & /@ polys;
 mPts = allPts // 
   TakeSmallestBy[Norm[p - #] &, 3];
 Show[polys,
  Table[
   Graphics[{
     Blend[{Green, Red}, (i - 1)/(Length[mPts] - 1)]
     , Line[{p, mPts[[i]]}]}]
   , {i, 1, Length[mPts]}
   ]
  ]
 , {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator}
 ]

Dynamic[Table[Norm[testPt - mPts[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[mPts]}]]
Dynamic[Ordering[Norm[testPt - #] & /@ allPts, 3]]
```

Comment: Something like a circumcircle?

Comment: No, I want to define the maximum distance `dmax` of any inner points of the circle. The resulting circle may be smaller than the extents of the polygons...

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @MarcoB I was thinking of a Voronoi-Approach, but I lack any experience with the application of it.

Comment: If you have not done so already I recommend that you ask this question on [Math.SE] for suggestions on the algorithm itself, which we can then help you implement optimally in *Mathematica*.

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised how poorly approaches such as `Polygon` + `RegionDistance` + `Max` + `MaxValue` seem to work on this problem. I assumed This problem would be solved easily - apparently not...

Comment: @kirma Yes, me too. I'm still hoping for some Voronoi-Expert ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final

```
pnts = {{0.3, 0}, {4, 2}, {4, -2}};
rotpnts =     Table[RotationTransform[2*Pi/3*i][pnts], {i, 0, 2}];
polys = BoundaryMeshRegion[#, Line[{1, 2, 3, 1}]] & /@ rotpnts;
reg = RegionUnion[polys]

regnp=ImplicitRegion[RegionDistance[reg,{x,y}]<2,{x,y}]

    regn=NDSolve`FEM`ToElementMesh[regnp,   MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> .1}, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> .001]

-SignedRegionDistance[regn,{0,0}]
```

---

The following code can generate you a correct result, but at a low speed:

```
pnts = {{0.3, 0}, {4, 2}, {4, -2}};
rotpnts = Table[RotationTransform[2*Pi/3*i][pnts], {i, 0, 2}];
polys = BoundaryMeshRegion[#, Line[{1, 2, 3, 1}]] & /@ rotpnts;
reg = RegionUnion[polys]

c[r_?NumericQ] := 
 NMaximize[
   RegionDistance[reg, {x, y}], {x, y} \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, r], 
   Method -> "NelderMead", PrecisionGoal -> 6, WorkingPrecision -> 10][[1]]
NMinimize[{r, c[r] > 2, 2<=r<=5}, r,Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing", PrecisionGoal -> 4, WorkingPrecision -> 10]

(*3.5439*)
```

The constraint is written in `c[r]>2`, you can customize the function to make it wider applicable.

The main idea of the code is quite simple, for each curve with coefficient `r`, in this case a circle with radius `r`, we can find out the largest distance we can get by moving the point on the curve by `RegionDistance` and `NMaximize`.

I strongly suggest adding `Method->"NelderMead"` as sometimes other method like `"DifferentialEvolution"` will find the distance always `0` (the searching point keeps in the region and never get out.) and stop evaluation.

Then we can find out the shortest `r` we need by `NMinimize`.

There's still one problem left, If we use `StepMonitor` to track the process, we can find out that no matter which method we choose, the process will not be ideal, so I think maybe we can create a simple form of `NMaximize` or so specially designed for this problem. Also, we can find out that sometimes the value has already reached the most optimized value but it still won't generate an output.

---

## Edit1

The second problem can be solved by `ConnectedMeshComponents` and `RegionNearest`.

```
res=NMaximize[ RegionDistance[reg, {x, y}], {x, y} \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, 3.5439(*the result*)], Method -> "NelderMead", PrecisionGoal -> 6, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
pt={x,y}/.res[[2]];
dis=res[[1]];
near=RegionNearest[#,pt]&/@ConnectedMeshComponents@DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[Disk[pt,dis+.1],reg]
Show[RegionPlot[reg],Graphics[{Line[{pt,#}]&/@near,Red,Point@pt,Blue,Point/@near}]]
```

[image: result]

---

## Edit2

I think you've got an answer by yourself already. This code can do the job you want:

```
pt = {3, 3};
n = 2;
near = RegionNearest[#, pt] & /@ ConnectedMeshComponents@reg
sel = TakeSmallestBy[near, EuclideanDistance[pt, #] &, n]
Show[RegionPlot[reg], 
 Graphics[{Line[{pt, #}] & /@ sel, Red, Point@pt, Blue, 
   Point /@ sel}]]
```

[image: img3]

---

## Edit3

Here gives a faster code optimized for this occasion:

pnts = {{0.3, 0}, {4, 2}, {4, -2}};
rotpnts = Table[RotationTransform[2*Pi/3*i][pnts], {i, 0, 2}];
polys = BoundaryMeshRegion[#, Line[{1, 2, 3, 1}]] & /@ rotpnts;
reg = RegionUnion[polys]

```
c[r_?NumericQ] := 
 NMaximize[
   SignedRegionDistance[reg, {x, y}], {x, y} \[Element] 
    Circle[{0, 0}, r], Method -> "NelderMead", PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 10][[1]]
find[tar_, range : {min_, max_}, prec_: .0001] := 
 Round[NestWhile[
    If[c@Mean@# > tar, Most, Rest][Subdivide[#[[1]], #[[2]], 2]] &, 
    N@range, #[[2]] - #[[1]] >= prec &][[1]], prec]
find[2, {2, 5}]

(*3.5439*)
```

Use simple and violent method to find out the smallest r in a given range, but this method can only apply when c[r] is monotony in the given range.

In this case, this is correct, so it can generate a correct result in a short amout of time.

Will this help?

---

## Edit4

A totally new method: inflation and calculate the minimum distance.

```
regn=Quiet@DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[RegionDistance[reg,{x,y}]<2,{x,y}],MaxCellMeasure->0.001]

-SignedRegionDistance[regn,{0,0}]
```

This method is widely applicable as long as your precision goal is not that high. Firstly, we create a new region to include every point in a distance to the region, then we find out at which distance finally there's a point not satisfying that, then this distance is just what you want!

Or maybe this will be even better in performance?

```
regnp=ImplicitRegion[RegionDistance[reg,{x,y}]<2,{x,y}]

regn=NDSolve`FEM`ToElementMesh[regnp,   MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> .1}, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> .001]
```

Comment: atm, I'm not at a PC, but I wonder how `r` is used in your `c[r_]`...

Comment: @DPF erer, sorry, I copied the test version, it should be Circle[{0,0},r]

Comment: @DPF corrected~ now this code works. :) extra is not hard as well, I will try to update soon

Comment: @DPF I'm currently without my computer, but I think maybe SignedRegionDistance will work better.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. Here, it doesn't come to a result within tens of seconds...

Comment: Concerning the second problem: I'd like to get the indices of the `n` closest polygons to a freely definable point.

Comment: @DPF can you illuatrate that with some examples?

Comment: @DPF also, I will try to improve the speed by customizing the minimum finding process.

Comment: I just added an illustration for the extra question

Comment: @DPF then you may try RegionNearest and TakeSmallest.

Comment: @DPF I'm at school so It's hard to write the code, but it's not hard.

Comment: If you take `Disk` instead of `Circle`, the function will always be monotony. Edit3 works much faster... Can you give a brief explanation of yout thoughts?

Comment: @DPF that's not good as I suppose you don't want the point always outside the region？

Comment: The point may occur anywhere in a Disk. I want to find the biggest Disk, where a given distance to at least one of the polygons is not exceeded

Comment: @DPF I've already solved that I suppose?

Comment: @DPF will edit3 fulfill your need?

Comment: I'll have to test your idea in my real scenario, where hundreds of polygons may occur. I need the answers in a resonable time, as I'll generate many variations of those polygon-lists.

Comment: @DPF use the third edit.

Comment: @DPF I'm finding a new solution

Comment: @DPF omg, check my new update.

Comment: Thats an interesting new approach. I appreciate your efforts on this problem. I'm going to accept your answer, even though I still have some other problems, related to the kind of my polygons in the list. I`ll open a new question for that.

Comment: @DPF thanks! Also, I like these problems as they have multiple approaches and diffenent approach fit in different problems.